# Angular HttpInterceptor and AccountService in Core Module - Multiple instances

Tags: angular

I've created CoreModule in my Angular 7

The core module contains `AccountService` and `HttpInterceptor` services:

```
providers: [..., AccountService,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: TokenInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }]
```

This is the ctor of AccountService:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient,
    @Inject('BASE_URL') public baseUrl: string,
    private router: Router,
    private notifierSrv: NotifierService) {
    ...
    console.log('new acc srv');
    ...
  }
```

The AccountService is injected to the HttpInterceptor service:

```
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private accountSrv: AccountService) {
        console.log(`TokenInterceptor init with acc: ${accountSrv}`);
    }
...
```

The main `AppModule` imports the CoreModule

**Problem**: During the first load of the app, I see ~300 creations of services in the browser console (Chrome) 
[Browser Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QR3m.png)

[image]

Also has this exception:

```
account.service.ts:43 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

The injector should create it as a singleton. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you share the full ctor of AccountService. The statements above and after the log statement

Comment: **sorry guys, my fault** did not realize I had an HTTP call during ctor and that caused a cyclic creation of the services, 10x!